# how I can send untype linq object to mvc view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

How I can send untype ling object to mvc view like this :

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
   var myUnTypeLinqQuery = from m in dbcontext.entity select new { f1, f2 };
   return [?]
}
```

in the razor view  what I should write ?:

@model [?]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The action should `return View(myUnTypeLinqQuery)`.

The view should use `@model IEnumerable<dynamic>`

Answer (score 0):

the action

```
return View(myUnTypeLinqQuery);
```

and in the view

```
@model dynamic
or
@model IEnumerable<dynamic>
```

if its a list.

Note: you dont have intellisense in the view for dynamic types